# Как можно улучшить этот код

Tags: python, python-3.x

Создал простую текстовую игрушку. Всё работает но я думаю что я слишком много не нужного написал так как я ток начинаю изучать python вот хочу спросить у опытных людей как можно или укоротить игру если это возможно или что то в ней улучшить

Есть парочку пожеланий. Первое это можно ли как то подсчет игр сделать вместе а не в разных функциях. Второе можно ли в моих функциях обойтись без global. Третье можно ли сделать так чтобы игра закрывалась именно по нажатию ENTER а не вписывать этот кастыль:

`exit_game = input('Нажмите ENTER чтобы выйти из игры: ')`

````
import random
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
from colorama import init
init()


#Cчетчики легкой сложности
win_easy = random.randint(1,50)
xod_easy = 0
good_try_easy = 0
all_try_easy = 0

#Cчетчики средней сложности
win_normal = random.randint(1,100)
xod_normal = 0
good_try_normal = 0
all_try_normal = 0

#Cчетчики сложной сложности
win_hard = random.randint(1,250)
xod_hard = 0
good_try_hard = 0
all_try_hard = 0

#Cчетчики игр
game_number_easy = 0
game_number_normal = 0
game_number_hard = 0
game_number_all = 0

#Подсчет легкой игры
def stats_easy ():
    global xod_easy
    global good_try_easy
    global all_try_easy
    all_try_easy += xod_easy
    if good_try_easy == 0:
        good_try_easy = 9999999999
    if xod_easy < good_try_easy:
        good_try_easy = xod_easy

#Подсчет средней игры
def stats_normal ():
    global xod_normal
    global good_try_normal
    global all_try_normal
    all_try_normal += xod_normal
    if good_try_normal == 0:
        good_try_normal = 9999999999
    if xod_normal < good_try_normal:
        good_try_normal = xod_normal

#Подсчет сложной игры
def stats_hard ():
    global xod_hard
    global good_try_hard
    global all_try_hard
    all_try_hard += xod_hard
    if good_try_hard == 0:
        good_try_hard = 9999999999
    if xod_hard < good_try_hard:
        good_try_hard = xod_hard

#Статистика всех игр после выходи из игры!
def stats_exit ():
    global xod_easy
    global good_try_easy
    global all_try_easy
    global xod_normal
    global good_try_normal
    global all_try_normal
    global game_number_easy
    global xod_hard
    global good_try_hard
    global all_try_hard
    global game_number_hard
    print(Fore.CYAN + '\nОбщее число игр: '+ str(game_number_all))
    print(Fore.GREEN + '\nСтатистика легкой сложности:\nХорошая попытка: '+ str(good_try_easy)
        + '\nВсего попыток: ' + str(all_try_easy) + '\nВсего игр: '
         + str(game_number_easy))
    print(Fore.MAGENTA + '\nСтатистика средней сложности:\nХорошая попытка: '+ str(good_try_normal)
        + '\nВсего попыток: ' + str(all_try_normal) + '\nВсего игр: '
         + str(game_number_normal))
    print(Fore.RED + Back.BLACK + '\nСтатистика сложной сложности:\nХорошая попытка: '+ str(good_try_hard)
        + '\nВсего попыток: ' + str(all_try_hard) + '\nВсего игр: '
         + str(game_number_hard))
    print(Fore.RESET + Back.RESET + Style.RESET_ALL)
    exit_game = input('Нажмите ENTER чтобы выйти из игры: ')

#Легкая игра (Логика)
def game_easy ():
    global win_easy
    global xod_easy
    global game_number_easy
    global game_number_all
    print(Fore.GREEN)
    print('Тут надо угадать число от 1 до 50')
    game_number_all += 1
    game_number_easy += 1
    while True:
        x = input('Введите число: ')
        if x.isdigit():
            x = int(x)
            xod_easy += 1
        else:
            print('Введите челое число!')
            continue
        if x == win_easy:
            print('Вы победили!\nЧисло попыток: ' + str(xod_easy))
            stats_easy ()
            xod_easy = 0
            next_try = input ('Хотите продолжить? Y/N: ')
            if next_try in ('Y','y','yes','Yes','YES'):
                win_easy = random.randint(1,50)
                game_number_all += 1
                game_number_easy += 1
                continue
            else:
                win_easy = random.randint(1,50)
                menu ()
                break
        elif x > win_easy:
            print('Загаданое число меньше')
            continue
        else:
            print('Загаданое число больше')
            continue

#Средняя игра (Логика)
def game_normal ():
    global win_normal
    global xod_normal
    global game_number_normal
    global game_number_all
    print(Fore.MAGENTA)
    print('Тут надо угадать чилсло от 1 до 100')
    game_number_all += 1
    game_number_normal += 1
    while True:
        x = input('Введите число: ')
        if x.isdigit():
            x = int(x)
            xod_normal += 1
        else:
            print('Введите челое число!')
            continue
        if x == win_normal:
            print('Вы победили!\nЧисло попыток: ' + str(xod_normal))
            stats_normal ()
            xod_normal = 0
            next_try = input ('Хотите продолжить? Y/N: ')
            if next_try in ('Y','y','yes','Yes','YES'):
                win_normal = random.randint(1,100)
                game_number_all += 1
                game_number_normal += 1
                continue
            else:
                win_normal = random.randint(1,100)
                menu ()
                break
        elif x > win_normal:
            print('Загаданое число меньше')
            continue
        else:
            print('Загаданое число больше')
            continue

#Сложная игра (Логика)
def game_hard ():
    global win_hard
    global xod_hard
    global game_number_hard
    global game_number_all
    print(Fore.RED)
    print('Тут надо угадать чилсло от 1 до 250')
    game_number_all += 1
    game_number_hard += 1
    while True:
        x = input('Введите число: ')
        if x.isdigit():
            x = int(x)
            xod_hard += 1
        else:
            print('Введите челое число!')
            continue
        if x == win_hard:
            print('Вы победили!\nЧисло попыток: ' + str(xod_hard))
            stats_hard ()
            xod_hard = 0
            next_try = input ('Хотите продолжить? Y/N: ')
            if next_try in ('Y','y','yes','Yes','YES'):
                win_hard = random.randint(1,250)
                game_number_all += 1
                game_number_hard += 1
                continue
            else:
                win_hard = random.randint(1,250)
                menu ()
                break
        elif x > win_hard:
            print('Загаданое число меньше')
            continue
        else:
            print('Загаданое число больше')
            continue

#Меню игры
def menu ():
    print(Fore.CYAN)
    print('Игра угадай число!')
    while True:
        difficul = input('Выберете сложность E/N/H/exit: ')
        if difficul in ('E','e'):
            game_easy ()
            break
        elif difficul in ('N','n'):
            game_normal ()
            break
        elif difficul in ('H','h'):
            game_hard ()
            break
        elif difficul in ('exit','Exit','EXIT'):
            print('\nСпасибо за игру!')
            stats_exit ()
            break
        else:
            print('Я не знаю такую команду. Попробуйте ещё раз.')

menu () #Запуск самой игры```
````

Comment: Обойтись без global можно и даже нужно. Так же не следует загромождать код continue и break. Они тут в большинстве случаев вообще ничего не дают.

Answer (score 0):

Я не сравнивал построчно, но похоже, что все три уровня идентичны и отличаются только верхней границей. Поэтому достаточно сделать одну функцию игры и передавать в неё верхнюю границу как параметр.

Comment: По сути да но там ещё меняется результат победы `win_easy = random.randint(1,50)` и подсчет очков `game_number_easy += 1`

Comment: В первую формулу как раз и надо подставить переменную с верхней границей. Для подсчёта очков придётся немного переделать.